# TCP/IP protocol and fragmentation

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

Using the TCP/IP protocol, given a connection between a client and a server, are the packets sent by the client to the server always received in the same order they were sent?

For example, if the client sends 3 packets of data, A, B and C, will the server always receive A first followed by B and C or is it possible for the server to receive C first, followed by A and B?

Comment: "**a** TCP/IP protocol"? Last time I checked, there's only **one** such protocol... and it's called TCP/IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using TCP, data is received by the destination application in the same order as it is sent by the source application.

See the following for more details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer

Comment: The packets can be reordered as they travel over the network. Packets moist definitely can be received out of order in TCP or any other protocol layered on top of IP.

Comment: @David: That may well be the case, but not as far as the application layer is concerned. He's not writing a TCP/IP stack, but an application. I've added this clarification to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: If your answer is supposed to be at application layer it's both incoherent and misleading. It's incoherent because there are no packets at application layer. It's misleading because it suggests a correspondence between the application layer byte stream and the data packet boundaries that does not exist -- a confusion that probably has caused more bugs in TCP-using applications than any other.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: of course there are no packets at the application layer, but as far as the application developer is concerned, s/he is guaranteed that the data sent by side A is always received in the same order by side B. Aren't we being a bit dramatic about bugs in TCP-using applications given this context? I'll delete the answer if you feel so strongly about it, unless you'd like to offer a correction.

Comment: I corrected the answer. I don't think I'm being overly dramatic because someone who is writing an application but asks about packet ordering likely doesn't have a clear understanding of the relationship between the TCP byte stream and the packets that carry that data. And it is the most frequent source of errors in TCP-using applications.

Comment: My concern was about..calling three times the socket function send() on one side of the server. With packet I meant this. but I apprechiate the corrections and the clarification of all of you.

Answer (score 5):

At IP level, packets may arrive in any order (if they arrive). At TCP level, the data stream is *guaranteed* to be ordered in the same manner on both ends.

That means *yes, the server will **always** receive A then B then C*. As long as you are using TCP.

Answer (score 3):

TCP is a transmission protocol, and it transmits data by sending the data out in IP packets over the underlying IP network. TCP is responsible for ensuring the correct transmission of the data, which includes ordering the arriving packets, re-requesting missing ones and discarding duplicates.

TCP as such does not expose any notion of "packet" to the user; the fact that the data is chunked into IP packets is a detail of the "over IP" implementation. A different implementation, e.g. TCP-over-bicycle-courier, might employ an entirely different scheme.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot happen that you receive data in a different order on the *application* side over a TCP socket.

It may happen that packets are received in a different order by the networking layer of the OS, but TCP makes it a requirement that the upper levels get data in order. It is the OS' role to ask again for unreceived fragments etc and assemble these fragments. So, you need not worry.

UDP, on the other hand, offers no such guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

The server (as the physical NIC of the machine) might receive them in any order. Your OS might receive them in any order again - that will mostly (but not allways) be the order of physical reception. Your client application is guaranteed to receive them in correct order, thats a property of TCP

Answer (score 0):

In general, packets will be received in the same order they are transmitted. But the network may drop or reorder packets. For example, packets may take different routes and arrive out of order. Packets may be lost or even duplicated on the network. The TCP implementation is responsible for retransmitting packets that are lost, acknowledging packets that are received, ignoring duplicated packets, all with the objective of accurately reconstructing the transmitted byte stream at the receiver.

At the application level, you send a stream of bytes and receive a stream of bytes. TCP does whatever is needed to ensure the received stream of bytes is identical to the sent stream of bytes, regardless of what happens to the packets on the network.